# Angular async pipe with rxjs switchmap

Tags: angular, typescript, rxjs, async-pipe

```
this.users$ = this.http.getUsers(criteria).pipe(
  switchMap(user => this.http.getUserData(user.id)),
  map(res => res.data)
);
```

I want to assign res.data to user.data
But the result is only res.data and its forgetting about user obejct
Any suggestions?

Comment: Compose the `map` onto the inner observable: `switchMap(user => this.http.getUserData(user.id).pipe(map(res => { user.data = res.data; return user; })))`

Answer (score 3):

This should do the trick for you.

```js
this.users$ = this.http.getUsers(criteria).pipe(
  switchMap(user => this.http.getUserData(user.id).pipe(
          map((res) => ({...user, data: res.data}))
  )),
);
```